# How to display a bitmap image in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, bitmap, mfc

I am trying to make a captcha application in Visual Studio 2013. I wrote all the code in C++ and it is generating the Bitmap image. Now i need to add a UI to this. Since, you cannot use Windows Forms Applications in Visual C++. I am trying to load a win32 console application and add the header files of MFC Application.

I can't figure out how to load the Bitmap images to display in the application. How do i achieve this task.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you can use win32 application to create a UI and update there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try
Project->Add New Item...->Visual C++->UI->Windows Forms
And then you can use the picturebox UI.